# ionizing body with tesla coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, tesla-coil

I have made a tesla coil.Now I want to ionize my body with it so that I can give shock to people with my hands.Is it possible to shock someone with it?

Comment: There is an interesting thing called the Darwin Awards and a whole site dedicated to these awards. I might suggest you look in to these awards carefully before proceeding with this activity.

Comment: and I am not too fool to use ac current which is 220 volts rather I will use 2 1.5 volts battery to make the tesla coil and I don't think  that I will get Darwin award for this.@kingchris

Comment: @Abtahee_Salekeen. Ok. As long as you are aware of the dangers. Even low voltage sources with the right step-up circuitry can provide enough of a jolt to interfere with a persons heart beat if delivered at the wrong time. I worked on microwave summing equipment and we always had to put one hand in your pocket so if a stray spark jumped at you it should not belt across your arms and potentially across your heart.

Comment: I'm willing to bet if you're running it off of 3v, it's not an actual Tesla coil. I'm betting it's just an oscillator and a transformer. Could you post the circuit please, @AbtaheeSalekeen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible but **very** dangerous. You will need to use the Tesla coil as a simple step up transformer rather than as a RF tuned circuit - and only run off very low voltages. If you aren't sure about any of this don't do it!

**Start with very low excitation voltages** - don't touch the high voltage side of the coil if it can generate sparks longer than about 1mm or so.

You will need to be very well insulated from the ground (and other objects) in order to hold the charge on your body. The 'low' side of the coil should be grounded - Try standing on a board raised off the floor on 4 glasses while getting your charge from the coil. Briefly touch the high voltage side of the coil, then step off the board and touch a separate ground point to see what sort of shock you get.

Don't forget that when you shock other people you will get a shock yourself.

Comment: Voltages won't matter. You'll get RF burns which can cause serious muscle and skin tissue damage. This is NOT OK!

Comment: @derstrom8 - I sort of assumed that with very low battery excitation he is using the tesla coil as step up transformer rather than as an RF tuned circuit. Bad assumption.

Comment: A Tesla coil IS a tuned RF circuit. That's how it operates. Without tuning it, you'll get little to no increase in voltage at the output.